# GWT code OR GWT Designer?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-designer

I am new to GWT. I have a question. Which way is better to learn/use GWT programming. Either to learn using GWT by writing code for creating user interface OR through GWT Designer? I am also aking this question in the context of good programming practices & industry requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that code is much better. Plus later on when you want to do more fine tuning of your UI, exact position up to the pixel level for example, I have found that the Designer is not very easy for aligning widgets. You will need to get down to the code level anyway to do so.

Another benefit like it was already mentioned is you will get a better understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's better to learn to code it from scratch.  That way you get a much better understanding of what the underlying code does.  Because you'll also have to consider supporting the GUI you develop as well.  And if you use a designer, while it's a lot quicker, it'll add it's own code to it, and it may not be pure GWT code.

So in my opinion, code it by hand, sure it'll take longer, but you'll understand it better, and be able to support it.  And it'll be another great skill to your bow.

Answer (score 2):

I use a mixed solution. Designer for main blocks and code for details...

Comment: this is the best approach , i am using in one of our project ,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start with coding rather than the designer. From a learning point of view, coding gives more information regarding how you can use and extend functionality.
Client side scripting involves good styling, alignment which you will understand once you work via the code and  scripts.